# How to use Arabic font in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

I am developing an application for Android in which I am using Custom fonts, I use more than 50 fonts but there is still same problem that if good running on 4.2.2 then collapse the words in 4.1.2.

```
Typeface itf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Quranic fonts.ttf");
    tt2.setTypeface(itf);
```

some of "Araaab " in arabic mix, some "Araabs" not showing proper and clear.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

The support of arabic fonts and others is still under heavy development (c.f. http://www.androidflux.com/android-4-2-2-jelly-bean-review.html). If you have a version that works with Android 4.1.2 and one with Android 4.2.2, you might consider releasing two different versions or, depending on the amount of work, check the version at runtime and use different implementations depending on that condition.

Comment: in 4.2.2supports the fonts, but in 4.1.2 it collapse and overlap some word with same font, if you tried please share the link or technique  for 4.1.2